# jquery tools problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

i have problem with any jquery tools download from http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html

none of them work.firebug give these error for all of them:

```
    function (a) {
  a.tools = a.tools || {
    version: "@VERSION"
  }, a.tools.tabs = {
    conf: {
      tabs: "a",
      current: "current",
      onBeforeClick: null,
      onClick: null,
      effect: "default",
      initialIndex: 0,
      event: "click",
      rotate: !1,
      history: !1
    },
    addEffect: function (a, c) {
      b[a] = c;
    }
  };
  var b = {
  default:


    function (a, b) {
      this.getPanes().hide().eq(a).show(), b.call();
    }, fade: function (a, b) {
      var c = this.getConf(),
          d = c.fadeOutSpeed,
          e = this.getPanes();
      d ? e.fadeOut(d) : e.hide(), e.eq(a).fadeIn(c.fadeInSpeed, b);
    },
    slide: function (a, b) {
      this.getPanes().slideUp(200), this.getPanes().eq(a).slideDown(400, b);
    },
    ajax: function (a, b) {
      this.getPanes().eq(0).load(this.getTabs().eq(a).attr("href"), b);
    }
  },
      c;
  a.tools.tabs.addEffect("horizontal", function (b, d) {
    c || (c = this.getPanes().eq(0).width()), this.getCurrentPane().animate({
      width: 0
    }, function () {
      a(this).hide();
    }), this.getPanes().eq(b).animate({
      width: c
    }, function () {
      a(this).show(), d.call();
    });
  });

  function d(c, d, e) {
    var f = this,
        g = c.add(this),
        h = c.find(e.tabs),
        i = d.jquery ? d : c.children(d),
        j;
    h.length || (h = c.children()), i.length || (i = c.parent().find(d)), i.length || (i = a(d)), a.extend(this, {
      click: function (c, d) {
        var i = h.eq(c);
        typeof c == "string" && c.replace("#", "") && (i = h.filter("[href*=" + c.replace("#", "") + "]"), c = Math.max(h.index(i), 0));
        if (e.rotate) {
          var k = h.length - 1;
          if (c < 0) {
            return f.click(k, d);
          }
          if (c > k) {
            return f.click(0, d);
          }
        }
        if (!i.length) {
          if (j >= 0) {
            return f;
          }
          c = e.initialIndex, i = h.eq(c);
        }
        if (c === j) {
          return f;
        }
        d = d || a.Event(), d.type = "onBeforeClick", g.trigger(d, [c]);
        if (!d.isDefaultPrevented()) {
          b[e.effect].call(f, c, function () {
            d.type = "onClick", g.trigger(d, [c]);
          }), j = c, h.removeClass(e.current), i.addClass(e.current);
          return f;
        }
      },
      getConf: function () {
        return e;
      },
      getTabs: function () {
        return h;
      },
      getPanes: function () {
        return i;
      },
      getCurrentPane: function () {
        return i.eq(j);
      },
      getCurrentTab: function () {
        return h.eq(j);
      },
      getIndex: function () {
        return j;
      },
      next: function () {
        return f.click(j + 1);
      },
      prev: function () {
        return f.click(j - 1);
      },
      destroy: function () {
        h.unbind(e.event).removeClass(e.current), i.find("a[href^=#]").unbind("click.T");
        return f;
      }
    }), a.each("onBeforeClick,onClick".split(","), function (b, c) {
      a.isFunction(e[c]) && a(f).bind(c, e[c]), f[c] = function (b) {
        b && a(f).bind(c, b);
        return f;
      };
    }), e.history && a.fn.history && (a.tools.history.init(h), e.event = "history"), h.each(function (b) {
      a(this).bind(e.event, function (a) {
        f.click(b, a);
        return a.preventDefault();
      });
    }), i.find("a[href^=#]").bind("click.T", function (b) {
      f.click(a(this).attr("href"), b);
    }), location.hash && e.tabs == "a" && c.find("[href=" + location.hash + "]").length ? f.click(location.hash) : (e.initialIndex === 0 || e.initialIndex > 0) && f.click(e.initialIndex);
  }
  a.fn.tabs = function (b, c) {
    var e = this.data("tabs");
    e && (e.destroy(), this.removeData("tabs")), a.isFunction(c) && (c = {
      onBeforeClick: c
    }), c = a.extend({}, a.tools.tabs.conf, c), this.each(function () {
      e = new d(a(this), b, c), a(this).data("tabs", e);
    });
    return c.api ? e : this;
  };
}(jQuery) is not a
function
```

And s'more code:

```
  (function (a) {
  a.tools = a.tools || {
    version...)
}; b.addEffect("apple", e, f)
})(jQuery);
```

please help me on this issue.

Comment: thank you.i guess there is something wrong in their download package maker.

Comment: Make sure you paste it in correctly. You seem to have omitted a few lines of code in the beginning...

Comment: the file is too long.you can get it from here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html by selecting all checkboxes.

Comment: You mean this: http://builder.jquerytools.org/v1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js?&include_jquery=true&t=tabs%2Ftabs.js&t=tabs%2Ftabs.slideshow.js&t=tooltip%2Ftooltip.js&t=tooltip%2Ftooltip.slide.js&t=tooltip%2Ftooltip.dynamic.js&t=scrollable%2Fscrollable.js&t=scrollable%2Fscrollable.autoscroll.js&t=scrollable%2Fscrollable.navigator.js&t=overlay%2Foverlay.js&t=overlay%2Foverlay.apple.js&t=dateinput%2Fdateinput.js&t=rangeinput%2Frangeinput.js&t=validator%2Fvalidator.js&t=toolbox%2Ftoolbox.flashembed.js&t=toolbox%2Ftoolbox.history.js&t=toolbox%2Ftoolbox.expose.js&t=toolbox%2Ftoolbox.mousewheel.js

Comment: yes,it is exactly it.the example is here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/chain.htm . if you save this page and replace its jquery file with what download from what you said,that error will be shown.

Comment: The thing I linked to includes jQuery test it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with his packaging tool; it's omitting the semicolon after each (jQuery). You can either include the full JS file from http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js, or add a semicolon after every instance of (jQuery), e.g. Find and replace (jQuery) with (jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying you have not loaded jQuery library.

Look under the `Net` tab in firebug and make sure you are actually loading jquery. If not, you either do not have the script tag in your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

Or if you do, the `src` is pointing to a jquery.js where it does not exist.